# Apache Pig deprecation errors

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a Hadoop (version 2.4.0) Cluster up and running. I have installed Pig and I have properly setup all the environment variables like `HADOOP_HOME`, `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`, `PIG_HOME` etc properly.

But still when I run my pig script in mapreduce mode, it throws a deprecation warning saying that `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS` which is incorrect as I have set it as `fs.defaultFS`.

Can anyone tell me why this deprecation error is popping up?

Answer (score 0):

Because your Hadoop configuration uses [deprecated properties](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html).

Check your core-site.xml

Comment: As I already mentioned, I am using the new properties in core-site.xml

Comment: Do you have a single Hadoop version installed?

Comment: I am sorry @kecso I did not quite get your question.

Comment: I'm usually working with an environment where multiple different Hadoop versions are installed. Each version has it's own conf files, so if you update a conf file you gave to be sure that conf is used. I've just ask if this is the case for you too.

Comment: No Sir. I have only one version of Hadoop installed.